# Lsh algorithm and band

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I read a lot of material about lsh algorithm but i've a question about it, exactly on band.

```
S1 = {1, 2, 4, 5} //band signatures for set S1
S2 = {5, 4, 4, 8} //band signatures for set S2
S3 = {1, 2, 4, 9} //band signatures for set S3
```

When i get all the minwise signatures of a set (e.g. S1) in a determinate band b what i have to do? I have to sum these signatures (e.g 1+2+4+5) or an or operator (e.g. 1 or 2 or 4 or 5) or what else?

Comment: There isn't *the* LSH algorithm. Which are you referring to?

Comment: Find near documents with locality sensitive hashing

Comment: That doesn't sound like the name of an algorithm. Can you provide any reference?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

I personally like to hash the band signatures to create an and like relationship between the signature, thus two data have a same banding-signature only if those data have all the same signature that define the bands

Answer (score 0):

In LSH you are talking about probability of two documents land on the same bucket. After generating the minhash, you should divide them into 'b' bands containing 'r' rows each. Then documents whose share the same bands are candidate to be similar. When finding candidates for given document is done, you can use whatever similarity measure you want to measure similarities and pick the k-most similar documents.